CSS Grid BarChart - Force new <li> items onto a new row without specifying grid-row-start
I am trying to create a configurable BarChart using only HTML/CSS...
I started with a tutorial from Josh Collingsworth:
https://joshcollinsworth.com/blog/css-grid-bar-charts
It uses a CSS GRID to auto-size based on the provided column-spans.
The problem I have (and he also explains in his example but doesnt give clearly a solution) is that if one of the items is large, the natural behaviour of GRID is to put the other items together on the next row(s) because there is enough space.
As I am trying to create a simple bar-chart, I want to force each item on a new row.


section {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem 2rem;
  border: 2px solid #a7a8aa;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.chart {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
  gap: 0.1em 0;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-left: 3px solid grey; 
}

li {
  background: gold;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.3rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0;
}
<section>
  <h2>Players per sports team</h2> 
  <ul class="chart">
    <li style="grid-column: span 11">
      Baseball:
      <span>11</span>
    </li>

    <li style="grid-column: span 4">
      Football:
      <span>4</span>
    </li>

    <li style="grid-column: span 3">
      Basketball:
      <span>3</span>
    </li>
    <li style="grid-column: span 3; grid-row-start:4;">
      Basketball:
      <span>3</span>
    </li>
  </ul> 
</section>



As my data will be dynamic, I am looking for a simple way through CSS to force each ListItem to start on a separate row.
I found that if I specify the row explicitly with each item it works, but it feels like I am missing something simple from the CSS which would accomplish the same thing ??
<li style="grid-column: span 4; grid-row-start: 1">
I also tried to force each ListItem to begin at column1 using grid-column-start:1 in the ListItem CSS but this doesnt work.

In fact the example does give an solution.

Fortunately, there’s an easy solution.
First, set grid-column-start: 1 on each grid item in your CSS;
Then, simply use grid-column-end instead of grid-column on each bar’s inline styles. (Either grid-column-end: span x;, or grid-column-end: x + 1; would work, where x is the data point’s value.)

This works.


section {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 30rem;
  padding: 1.5rem 1.5rem 2rem;
  border: 2px solid #a7a8aa;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.chart {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  gap: 0.1em 0;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  border-left: 3px solid grey;
}

li {
  background: gold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 0 0.5em 0.5em 0;
  grid-column-start: 1;
}
<section>
  <h2>Players per sports team</h2>
  <ul class="chart">
    <li style="grid-column-end: 11">
      Baseball:
      <span>11</span>
    </li>

    <li style="grid-column-end: 3">
      Football:
      <span>3</span>
    </li>

    <li style="grid-column-end: 4">
      Volleyball:
      <span>4</span>
    </li>
    <li style="grid-column-end: 3;">
      Basketball:
      <span>3</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>




Thanks @Paulie_D . I don't know how I missed that comment :( I've read the article about 10 times over the last week & I tried several other things but the solution he/you present is quite obvious when you take a step back & think about it...
Thanks again....
